# cmake check if library is static

Tags: cmake

Is there a way to check if a found library is a static library? In order to find the library I do this:

```
IF(WIN32)
    SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .lib)
ELSE()
    SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .a)
ENDIF()
find_library(QUANTLIB_LIBRARY NAMES QuantLib PATHS ${QUANTLIB_LIBRARY_SEARCH})
```

But on windows a `.lib` could be the symbol file for a DLL. I need to ensure this is actually the static form of the library, otherwise linking later will result in hard-to-understand error messages.

---

*In case you're wondering, I don't really want to use a satic library, but QuantLib is broken with respect to multithreading and shared libraries. This is my best chance at getting it working correctly: statically link to one of my shared libraries.*

Answer (score 11):

If the library is added as a target properly you should be able to do something like this.

```
get_target_property(target_type your_target_name TYPE)
if (target_type STREQUAL STATIC_LIBRARY)
  ...
```

See [`TYPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/TYPE.html) for details.

Comment: That's the ticket. It works even for imported libraries (using find_package) - those libraries, after all, provide a .cmake file that simply does `add_library(... STATIC)` :)

Comment: Unfortunately I've found that they often end up as `UNKNOWN_LIBRARY`. E.g. `FindBoost.cmake` does this. I ended up using string matching on the filename. Very ugly and doesn't work in the general case on Windows but fortunately Boost puts `-s-` in its static library filenames on Windows.

Comment: Boost's cmake support is broken then :(