# Detect static Qt in cmake

Tags: qt, cmake, static-linking

How can I detect if the used version of Qt is statically built in a cmake project?

My goal is to make my project files independent from the version of Qt that is used to build it, and there are a few places where I need to differ between dynamic and static builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like for every other library in cmake, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406750/cmake-check-if-library-is-static):

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
get_target_property(MY_QT_TARGET_TYPE Qt5::Core TYPE)
if(MY_QT_TARGET_TYPE STREQUAL STATIC_LIBRARY)
    message("Qt was built as a static library!")
endif()
```